# Android Cordova - switch back to my app even if other apps are open

Tags: android, cordova

I am making an app for a small household IOT device. I have a service running in my app which continuously works in the background.

My problem is if I detect an error or something that needs user attention, how do I programatically switch to my app even if the user is on some other app.

Example scenario:

1. User runs MyApp
2. User then goes to some other app (can be any app installed on that device)
3. The service running inside MyApp detects that MyApp needs user attention.
4. Hence, MyApp comes to the foreground

How do I achieve the 4th step programatically?

Edit: Sorry forgot to mention - I am using cordova. I am making plugin for myself (which necessarily is just android code).

Comment: In you service whenever such condition arises call Intent to open you activity or triger a notification

Answer (score 0):

Fire a intent from service to open your main activity.

```
Intent Intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(Intent);
```

Comment: I am using cordova. When I want to launch some other app, this code works for me - `Intent launchIntent = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(id);
                            cordova.getActivity().startActivity(launchIntent);` But after that when I want to come back to my app, this code is not working - `Intent intent = new Intent(cordova.getActivity(), cordova.getActivity().getClass());
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);`